# Contact Form 7 - E-mail message template

Tags: email, plugin-contact-form-7

In contact form 7 email settings, I put in all the necessary details like below:

[image]
However, when the e-mail is sent, it still has the "Wordpress" title or person who sent it in gmail:

[image]
[image]

What am I missing? Did I set something up wrongly?

Any piece of advice or information would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the field "From" you can enter both a name and e-mail like this:

`YOUR-NAME <email@example.com>`

Or with info from the form it self: `[name-field-name] <[email-field-name]>`